# What makes the web container to load web.xml first of all in a web application?

Tags: java, tomcat, web

Where is this configuration done (in which file, say in Tomcat) that decides that the web.xml file will be the first to be loaded by the web container when it gets started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it's looking for a file named `web.xml` isn't specific to Tomcat, but to the Java Servlet specification. The file format for a `WAR` file says that you should have a file named like that:

> There are special files and directories within a WAR file:
>
> The /WEB-INF directory in the WAR file contains a file named web.xml which defines the structure of the web application.

From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)

Answer (score 0):

```
/home/abc/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/conf/web.xml
```

If you pass the positive value, the lower integer value servlet will be loaded before the higher integer value servlet. In other words, container loads the servlets in ascending integer value. The 0 value will be loaded first then 1, 2, 3 and so on.

for ex:

```
<servlet>  
   <servlet-name>servlet2</servlet-name>  
   <servlet-class>com.abc.xyz</servlet-class>  
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>
```

There are defined 2 servlets, both servlets will be loaded at the time of project deployment or server start. But, servlet1 will be loaded first then servlet2.
[load on startup in web.xml](https://www.javatpoint.com/load-on-startup)